# unison: how to sync specific subfolders in several directories?

Tags: ubuntu, unison

I am trying to sync a subset of my directories between two machines (both ubuntu 16.04) with unison (version 2.48.3). On both machines, I have a directory called "research". It contains a folder for each project that I am working on. Within each of these folders, there is a folder named "lit", and I would like to synchronize all those "lit" folders with unison, without really having to care about the project names themselves.
Example: on both machines, there are the following folders:

```
/home/chris/research/projA/lit
/home/chris/research/projA/otherstuff
/home/chris/research/projB/lit
/home/chris/research/projB/otherstuff
```

And of these I want to sync `projA/lit` across the two machines, and also `projB/lit`.

I have installed unison, and read myself through the manpage. based on that, I have modified the unison profile file default.prf as follows:

```
# Unison preferences file
# used for syncing lit between work and home

# roots
root = /home/chris/research
root = ssh://pc-work//home/chris/research

# paths
path = */lit
```

While unison connects successfully to my work computer, it does not find anything to sync.
If in contrast, I replace in the above profile `path = */lit` with `path = projA/lit`, it works.

Thus, the question: can I get unison to sync the `lit` subfolder for all projects without having to specify these, and if so, how? Or do I have to wrap the unison command in some sort of loop in order to iterate through all project folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`path` is not the right way to achieve what you want. From the [documentation](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html) on `path`:

> Note that `path` preferences are intepreted literally—they are not regular expressions.

Even though you're not using a regular expression, but a shell glob, I take the above to mean that the value of `path` isn't interpreted specially by `unison`.

You could achieve the effect you're after, though, by judicious use of `ignore` and/or `ignorenot`. Those *do* allow shell globs or regular expressions.

For example, (disclaimer: I haven't tested this)

```
ignore = Path proj*/otherstuff
```

for any directory that you want to skip while synchronizing. You could also specify it the other way around, if you have more directories to skip than to synchronize:

```
ignore = Path proj*/*
ignorenot = Path proj*/lit
```

Note that you don't need to set `path` if the files and directories you want to synchronize are already directly under the `root` you specify.